# Manual run of SpringLiquibase uses wrong timezone

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, cucumber, h2, liquibase

I use liquibase to reset my database between tests.  From a standard spring boot run at the start of my tests it inserts data with the correct TZ. When I run it manually, it applies a different TZ.

I have application.properties set up with `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC` and liquibase enabled.  When inserting time data into a time column, it inserts `12:00:00` without issue.

When I try to rerun liquibase between my tests, everything is fine except times are inserted with the current local TZ (+01:00) giving me `13:00:00` instead.

```
@Autowired
SpringLiquibase liquibase;

public void clean() {
   liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
   liquibase.setDropFirst(true);
   liquibase.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

There is a `setChangelogProperties` method, but I cannot find documentation for any TZ related stuff.

I have tried reinjecting the DataSource, tried TIME, TIME WITHOUT TIMEZONE, but to no avail.

When re-running the same SpringLiquibase bean run during the application initialisation I would expect the same TZ info and any other config to be maintained and reused.

### UPDATE

After trying many different timezone settings throughout the tests, the only thing that has worked is -Duser.timezone=UTC from the command line.

Setting this as `System.setProperty("-Duser.timezone","UTC")` as early as I can, and also prior to re-running liquibase has no effect.

Is there a way I can get spring to set this for before it loads everything?

It is strange that the first run via spring is fine, but consequent ones appear to lose the timezone setting.

### UPDATE 2

Setting `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))` either never gets picked up or does not happen early enough.

Adding the following to my test runner

```
    static {
        System.setProperty("UTC");
    }
```

also appears to not execute earlier enough, or does not get propagated properly to liquibase.

It definitely feels like SpringLiquibase is going by its own rules, or something strange is happening with the driver loading

Comment: Perhaps something like `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:{your-database}?serverTimezone=UTC` will help

Comment: H2 does not support a timezone parameter at the moment, and loads with the timezone of the JVM. It seems I just can't set the timezone early enough though before the driver loads

Answer (score 3):

Just had this issue because liquibase was loading H2 before the timezone was set. As you've noticed there's an important gap between setting the Timezone on the JVM/command-line, and the first time you have access to the code to set it in the test.

Earlier than ContextRefreshedEvent even, you have to use a custom ApplicationContextInitializer (kotlin, soz):

```
class MyInitializer() : ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
  @Override
  override fun initialize(applicationContext: ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneOffset.UTC))
  }
}
```

then to register it, add to a property class:
`context.initializer.classes=com.foo.MyInitializer`